# Ionic - getting {isTrusted:true} from eventListener

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, cross-domain

I'm sending a cross origin request in ionic from the main page into an iFrame, when I attach the event listener I catches the event, but I can't access the data I passed, all the parameter contains is {isTrusted:true}

Is this related to CORS?

Comment: Were u able to resolve this?